# How to skip navigating by URL if it takes too long or the connection has timed out problem

Tags: puppeteer

I was scraping a website to collect a list of URL and then navigate those URL and again collect some data. Everything work perfect until I navigate a URL which is death. My whole scraping process was broke and lost collected data. Is their any way to skip naviagte that page when it took long time or when connection has timed out problem like [this one](http://becauseyoumattersite.com/)

```js
 for (let i = 0, n= listURL.length; i < n; i++) {
    await page.goto(listURL[i], { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' }); //<--- crash here 
    console.log(`navigate ${URLS[i]}`);
    //collect data
    address = await page.url() // <-- here also crashed
  }
```

Comment: When it crashes, what's the error? "Everything work perfect until I navigate a URL which is death." -- isn't navigating the first thing you pretty much always do in Puppeteer? `n= listURL.length; i < n` is unnecessary, just use `i < listURL.length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use [timeout](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.2.1/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options).**

[image]

```
for (let i = 0, n= listURL.length; i < n; i++) {
    try {
        await page.goto(listURL[i], { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 100 }); //<--- crash here 
    } catch (err) {
        if(err.name === 'TimeoutError') {
            continue; // or do some thing
        } else {
            throw err; // or do some thing
        }
    }
    console.log(`navigate ${URLS[i]}`);
  }
```

**Update 1**

For Your [example](https://pastebin.com/gFXwptKk). this problem here because you handle one type of error so if the `page.goto()` throw anther type of error you will not handle it so the app will skip `address = await page.url();` and go to `throw err` so to handle it you will catch any type of errors.

```
try {
    await page.goto(websiteTempUrl, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
        timeout: 70000,
    });
    address = await page.url();
} catch (err) {
    address = 'dead linked';
}
```

Comment: thanks @Ahmed ElMetwally for your response. I tried to use `timeout: 70000` although the program crashed for dead link when I tried to get the current url `address = await page.url()`. For make it clear [here](https://pastebin.com/gFXwptKk) I give you the code. it will be great help if you help me to resolve this error

Comment: This is anther type for error. so to handle it you should delete `if(err.name === 'TimeoutError')`. I will update my answer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to come back and accept your answer @Ahmed ElMetwally

Comment: `{ waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 100 }` is an "always throw" configuration from what I can discern. The [docs](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.goto/#remarks) say: "networkidle2 : consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 2 network connections for at least 500 ms." but you're giving up and timing out after 100 ms. Most sites take at least a few seconds to finish loading. 100 ms is a tenth of a second. 70000 ms in your second code block makes more sense.